# jQuery delay()/fadeIn() not working. Console is fine

Tags: jquery

I want a popup ot appear 5 seconds after the document has loaded. The solution below doesn't seem to be working, I get zero console errors. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tstaLqd3/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>

    </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      div{
        width:600px;
        height: 250px;
        border:2px solid black;
      }

    </style>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#popup').delay(5000).fadeIn(1);
     });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup">
    yada yada
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `#popup` is already visible and you are trying to `fadeIn()`, hide it first and then try `fadeIn()` after 5s delay.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/tstaLqd3/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#popup').hide();
    $('#popup').delay(5000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the css property `display:none`

```
</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  div{
    width:600px;
    height: 250px;
    border:2px solid black;
    display:none;
  }

</style>  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup').delay(5000).fadeIn();
 });

</script>
```

yada yada

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

Element can't have fadeIn effect when it's already visible. means first need to hide the element and then fading it in.

```
$('#popup').hide().delay(5000).fadeIn(1);
```

Comment: Please add some context/explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Edited the comment your highness