# Delay popup loading after click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

All I need it to do is delay the popup from "popping" for a few seconds after clicking a button. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#element-167 a').on("click", function() {
    $('.modal-dialog').delay(5000).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add HTML and CSS

Comment: please add HTML and CSS

Comment: If a link you likely also want `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954451/jquery-delay-fadein-not-working-console-is-fine

Comment: unfortunately I am using a website builder and there's so much code to sort through, I was just wondering if the code is written correctly in theory or if I am missing something obvious to others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `queue()` and pass a function as parameter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#element-167 a').on("click", function() {
    $(".modal-dialog").delay(5000).queue(() => {
      // Do things after 5 seconds
      $('.modal-dialog').fadeIn();
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selected').on("click", function() {
      setTimeout(()=>{alert("Message here")},5000)
  });
});

<p id="selected">This is second paragraph.</p>
```